# Как сэмулировать нажатие кнопки в консоли

Tags: javascript, textarea

Есть input type=textaera, который отправляет сообщение на сервер только при нажатии на enter (как во всеми любимом вконтакте), как можно отправить сообщение на сервер через консоль, не нажимая enter? 
P.S. добавление в input.value '\n' не работает
P.S.S на чистом js[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Вот сюда при вводе сообщения отправляется сообщение нажатием на enter]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically

Comment: А я так и не понял работает ли добавление String.fromCharCode(13);?

Comment: @EliotAlderson net

Comment: я что то не понял вроде уже задали такой вопрос и почему ещё одну тему создаете? может покажете свой код (хотяб хтмл) чтоб отвечающие не гадали что к чему...

Comment: Добавь больше кода, который содержит html и код, который показывает как функция связана с инпутом

Comment: @MuzaffarRasulov  добавил скриншоты, в то поле при вооде и нажатии enter отправляется сообщение

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin проверяйте

Comment: @Sergey код лучше вставлять кодом, а не картинкой и добавьте ваш is код, чтобы видеть ваши попытки

Answer (score 0):

> Как можно отправить сообщение на сервер через консоль, не нажимая
>   enter?

Пример эмуляции нажатия `Enter`:

```js
// Для демострации элемента
var d = document.querySelector('.content')
// Вешаем событие или оно уже есть, и риагирует на триггер
d.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  // Печатает keyCode при нажатии Enter
  console.log("This is:", e.keyCode);
})
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Собственно сам триггер события Enter (13)
d.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {
  keyCode: 13
}))
```

```css
.content {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <!-------- Элемент который слушает событте Enter -------->
</div>
```

---

[Доки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

---

Пример с отправкой содержимого на условный сервер:

```js
// Для демострации элемента
var d = document.querySelector('.content')
var t = document.querySelector('textarea')
t.value = "Show me the money"
// Вешаем событие или оно уже есть, и риагирует на триггер
d.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  // Печатает keyCode при нажатии Enter
  console.log("This is:", e.keyCode);
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Отправка чего-либо
  var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
  fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        some: t.value
      }) // Отправка самого поля
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))

})
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Собственно сам триггер события Enter (13)
d.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {
  keyCode: 13
}))
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <!-------- Элемент который слушает событте Enter -------->
  <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

---

[fetch доки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: В этом то вся и проблема, как это сделать ?!
Этот код пишет только код нажатой клавиши, не больше

Comment: @Sergey добавил, код отправки.

Comment: Не то, всё равно. Но спасибо за попытку, что-ли xD

Answer (score 0):

Используй WinSpy или Winexp. Чтобы найти класс и имя консольного окна.
Для поиска окна и эмуляции нажатия клавиш используй WinAPI функции.
FindWindow, FindWindowEx, SendMessage с параметром WM_KEYDOWN и нужной клавишей.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 
 
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
 
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
            string lpWindowName);
 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
 
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
        const int WM_CHAR = 0x0102;
        
 
 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
 
          
            Console.Title = "con_wi";
 
            IntPtr handle = FindWindow(@"ConsoleWindowClass", @"con_wi");
            
            
           
 
            if (handle == null) Console.Write("null handle");
 
 
 
            SendMessage(handle, WM_CHAR, (int)'!', null);
            Console.ReadKey();
 
            for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++) { SendMessage(handle, WM_CHAR, i, null); Console.ReadKey(); }
 
 
              
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

примерно так?